SQL Server Docker cannot persist data after exit the sqlcmd program
I got the SQL Server image running in the docker now. When I input a .sql file into sqlcmd in the container, the data is inserted in the table. But when I login and check it again in the sqlcmd it is empty. I am not sure what is going on here, I have attached the file below, any help is appreciated.
docker-compose.yaml
version: '3'
services:
  # /opt/mssql-tools18/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P $MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD -C -i /setup/dbSetup.sql
  sql-server:    
    container_name: sql-server-2022
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Root!234
    volumes:
      - ./sqlVolumn:/var/opt/mssql
      - ./dbSetup.sql:/setup/dbSetup.sql
      - ./dbConnectionStr.sql:/setup/dbConnectionStr.sql


dbSetup.sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'FlashCardsDB')
  BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE [FlashCardsDB]
  END
GO

USE [FlashCardsDB]
GO

-- IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='TableName' and xtype='U')
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FlashCards;
CREATE TABLE FlashCards (
    cardId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, -- GUID
    question VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    answer VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (cardId)
);
GO

INSERT INTO FlashCards(cardId, question, answer, status) VALUES ('3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6', 'What is smallest prime number', '2', 'pass');
INSERT INTO FlashCards(cardId, question, answer, status) VALUES ('b736b3f4-dadd-4c71-82d1-37774e733fc8', 'How many hours in a day', '24', 'fail');
INSERT INTO FlashCards(cardId, question, answer, status) VALUES ('e844faab-32bc-4f9b-9332-b1123a9652f4', 'What is the first month in a year', 'January', 'pass');
GO

SELECT Name from sys.databases; 
GO
SELECT cardId, question, answer, status FROM FlashCards; 
GO
 


Provide more context, is this happening between restarts?

It is not working even the container keeps running while executing the sql file in sqlcmd. Not working restart the container or restart my mac.

Where is the part that inputs the file into sqlcmd? And what's the output of that input?

/opt/mssql-tools18/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P $MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD -C -i /setup/dbSetup.sql input the file. The output shows that 3 rows effected, means the data is successfully inserted. But it is gone when I login and check the table again.
